# Retrieve same column of a table for 2 different columns in another table

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables "users" and "transactions". Users table contains userid ans name. Transactions table contains senderid, receiverid and amount. I want to get the names of both sender and receiver. Senderid and receiverid are foreign keys of users.userid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `join` to the `users` table multiple times:

```
select s.name, r.name, t.amount
from transactions t
    join users s on t.senderid = s.userid
    join users r on t.senderid = r.userid
```

If there are user ids in the `transactions` table that does not exist in the `users` table, you'll need to use an `outer join` instead.